# How to add a Property Name and Value to a JavaScript Object using a function?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```
var a = "the letter a";
var obj = {};

obj.brovo = "the letter b";
obj.charlie = "the letter c";

if (!obj.alpha) obj.alpha = a;
```

Since I wish to use this at different points in my code and will be using it multiple times I wish for it to be used as the following:

```
isNotSet(obj.alpha, a);
```

I wish this to equate `obj.alpha = a;`

I started with the following function:

```
function isNotSet (arg1, arg2) {
    if (!arg1) arg1 = arg2;
    return arg1;
}
```

Comment: You need not return the value. As the variable is passed by reference

Comment: why the down vote? this is :( this is my first question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is really just a simple one-liner:

```
obj.alpha = obj.alpha || a;
```

If you really need a function, you can wrap it:

```
function isNotSet(obj, arg1, arg2) {
    obj[arg1] = obj[arg1] || arg2;
}
```

You should be aware, though, that both this solution and your proposed solution will overwrite the value if `obj[arg1]` is set to `false` (or any other falsy value).

If you want to handle those values properly, the easiest way would be:

```
function isNotSet(obj, arg1, arg2) {
    if(typeof obj[arg1] !== "undefined" && obj[arg1] !== null) { return; }
    obj[arg1] = arg2;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps 0 is considered valid though.

Comment: @Comptonburger - I mentioned that shortcoming in my answer.

Comment: @Comptonburger - Added another function that only defaults for `null` and `undefined`. Still doesn't check property ownership.

Comment: I did not think about falsy - TY

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this with the following function:

```
isNotSet('alpha', a);
```

I just take the arg1 as just the Property Name then add it to the object then assign the value to that object with the Property Name.

```
function isNotSet (arg1, arg2) {
    if (!obj[arg1]) obj[arg1] = arg2;
}
```

Comment: That's not the best solution, because the object is being accessed via it's global scope.  This will **only work** for that object variable named `obj` in your code.

Comment: You might want to use `hasOwnProperty` instead of `!obj[arg1]` but that depends on how you wont to handle `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `false` and empty string.